# How to count a character in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Please help me - I have problem with counting how many 'a' (character) there are in a row and column.

This is my query :

```
declare @zz as varchar(10) = '123a123a12'
select @zz
```

What function in SQL Server 2008 R2 can I use to count how many 'a' are in there?

How can I combine `charindex` with `len`?

Thanks

Comment: Please, refer updated answer. it helps you to find out char from a sting.

Answer (score 2):

The old school trick here is to replace the 'a's with empty spaces ('') and compare the resulting string's length to the length of the original:

```
declare @zz as varchar(10) = '123a123a12' 

declare @zz_without_a varchar(10)=replace(@zz,'a','')

declare @a_in_zz int=len(@zz)-len(zz_without_a)
```

Answer (score 0):

One possibe approach is to use [REPLACE()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/replace-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) and [LEN()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/len-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) functions.:

```
DECLARE @zz varchar(10) = '123a123a12' 
SELECT LEN(@zz) - LEN(REPLACE(@zz, 'a', '')) AS CharCount
```

Output:

```
CharCount
        2
```

Another possible approach, if you want to count more than one character, is to use recursion:

```
DECLARE @zz varchar(10) = 'aa3a123a12' 
;WITH cte AS (
   SELECT 1 AS N
   UNION ALL
   SELECT N + 1
   FROM cte
   WHERE N < LEN(@zz)
)
SELECT COUNT(*) AS CharCount
FROM cte
WHERE SUBSTRING(@zz, N, 1) IN ('a', '1')
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `REPLACE` and **`DATALENGTH`** instead of `LEN`, because of trailing spaces that could appear after replace.
Example:

```
DECLARE @zz as varchar(20) = '123a123a12      a' 
SELECT DATALENGTH(@zz) - DATALENGTH(REPLACE(@zz, 'a', '')),
    LEN(@zz) - LEN(REPLACE(@zz, 'a', ''))
```

The output is 3 and 9.
If @zz is `NVARCHAR`, not `VARCHAR`, you will have to divide by 2.

From MSDN:

> DATALENGTH function returns the number of bytes used to represent any
>   expression